# Input to reshape is a tensor with 4104 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 96

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm new to tensorflow and I want to do some time series forecasting and followed [this](https://mapr.com/blog/deep-learning-tensorflow/) link. I want to have 36 hours data as input and next consecutive 48 hour as output data so I made x and y batches as follows:

```
""" Making our training dataset with batch size of num_period """
x_batches = {'NSW': X_NSW.transpose().reshape(-1,72,1),
             'QLD': X_QLD.transpose().reshape(-1,72,1),
             'SA': X_SA.transpose().reshape(-1,72,1),
             'TAS': X_TAS.transpose().reshape(-1,72,1),
             'VIC': X_VIC.transpose().reshape(-1,72,1)}

y_batches = {'NSW': Y_NSW.transpose().reshape(-1,96,1),
                 'QLD': Y_QLD.transpose().reshape(-1,96,1),
                 'SA': Y_SA.transpose().reshape(-1,96,1),
                 'TAS': Y_TAS.transpose().reshape(-1,96,1),
                 'VIC': Y_VIC.transpose().reshape(-1,96,1)}
```

Then I used the same code as given in the link above (but modified it according to need) and got the following code:

```
inputs = 1  #input vector size
hidden = 100    
output = 1  #output vector size

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 72, inputs])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 96, output])

basic_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicRNNCell(num_units=hidden, activation=tf.nn.relu)
rnn_output, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(basic_cell, X, dtype=tf.float32)

learning_rate = 0.001   #small learning rate so we don't overshoot the minimum

stacked_rnn_output = tf.reshape(rnn_output, [-1, hidden])           #change the form into a tensor
stacked_outputs = tf.layers.dense(stacked_rnn_output, output)        #specify the type of layer (dense)
outputs = tf.reshape(stacked_outputs, [-1, 96, output])          #shape of results
```

But the system is throwing me following error

```
outputs = tf.reshape(stacked_outputs, [-1, 96, output])          #shape of results

...

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Input to reshape is a tensor with 4104 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 96
     [[Node: Reshape_1 = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](dense/BiasAdd, Reshape_1/shape)]]
```

I know I'm making some mistake in the following line but I'm unable to figure it out.

```
stacked_rnn_output = tf.reshape(rnn_output, [-1, hidden])           #change the form into a tensor
stacked_outputs = tf.layers.dense(stacked_rnn_output, output)        #specify the type of layer (dense)
outputs = tf.reshape(stacked_outputs, [-1, 96, output])          #shape of results
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem concerns how you set up your task. A RNN outputs a single value for any single input: if your input sequence is 72-step long you your output sequence will be 72-step long, you can't ask for reshaping into a 96-step long sequence.

Two solutions (but clearly it depends on what you are currently asking to your algorithm to learn):

1. **Cut the output**: you are interested only in the first 72 elements of the output sequence since you have an input of that size.
2. **Pad the input**: you are still interested in an output of 96 elements but you don't know the input for the last 96 - 72 steps. You put a zero pad for unknown input and let the state of the RNNCell to make your predictions.